# Maven assembly plugin jar with dependencies - plugin not running

Tags: java, maven, jar

I've got a Maven project (submodule of a parent project) which I need to create a "jar with dependencies" for.  I added the `maven-assembly-plugin` to the pom.xml, but it didn't create the artifact.   I've slowly stripped everything else out of the pom.xml, until all that's left is dependencies and this plugin, and it still won't create a jar with dependencies.   Watching the output of `mvn clean package` it runs `clean`, `compile`, and `jar` but never runs the `assembly` plugin.   I don't know why.   Here's the pom.xml, can anyone spot the problem?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-name</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>project-name</name>

    <properties>
        <build.time>${maven.build.timestamp}</build.time>
        <spring.framework.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
        <spring.security.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <spring.webflow.version>2.4.2.RELEASE</spring.webflow.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        [snip]
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: You need to attach it to a life cycle phase.

Comment: That appears to be working.   Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Maven reference](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html) :

> Assemble an application bundle or distribution from an assembly
>   descriptor. This goal is suitable either for binding to the lifecycle
>   or calling directly from the command line (provided all required files
>   are available before the build starts, or are produced by another goal
>   specified before this one on the command line).

The `asssembly:single` goal may be used in two ways :

- either by binding it to the lifecycle
- or by calling it directly from the command line

You do no one of them.

You can for example do it to bind the plugin execution to the `package` phase :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now the `mvn package` or `mvn install` command will create the jar with dependencies.

You can also keep your actual plugin configuration and run the `mvn assembly:single` command.

The second way allows to create the jar with dependencies on demand and not for every build.
Which may be desirable if the jar creation is a long task that doesn't need to be executed at each build.

Comment: It's odd that this simple bit of information doesn't appear explicitly in the Maven plugin documentation, but has to be deduced by reading two separate sections and putting them together.   Ah, well.  It's free.